# npm search hangs on windows 8.1

Tags: npm, webstorm

I am trying to figure out a problem with WebStorm 8's NPM UI tool. I have come to a point that running "npm search" command line actually hangs. That is what the UI tool runs initially. I am running Windows 8.1. I have also tried running the same command in Windows 7. It actually returns an error running the "npm search" command. I really want to run WebStorm with NPM on windows 8.1.

Comment: Does `npm search` work when executed in Windows console? For me it does not (Windows 7 x64; node 0.10.31 x64).

Comment: npm search hangs in the cmd console, but npm search fooBar works. I just want to get WebStorm 8 to work. It somehow tries to run "npm search" and it will just stuck there.

Comment: I just tested it on Windows 7 64 bit. npm search doesn't work initially. I have to do a "npm -g install npm". It is hanging like it is on Windows 8 now when I run "npm search".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is a Windows only problem. Instead it looks exactly like this reported bug: [npm.commands.search fails and dumps 100+ Mb to output log](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6016)

I can reproduce it on Linux with npm 2.0.2 by simply calling

```
npm search
```

(It just hangs and allocates huge amounts of memory)

To quote from the bug report:

> We're treating the combined metadata for all packages in the registry as an in-memory database backed by a JSON file. It's already a hefty wad of data to download, parse, and keep in memory, and as the number of packages in the registry grows, it's going to cause more and more problems, especially in resource-constrained environments

Let us hope they can fix it soon.

(Another related bug report is [npm search" runs out of memory and dies without good error](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3867). Looks like a duplicate to me.)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on OSX 10.9.4.  Via command line, 'npm search' fails with "FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory".  Via PHPStorm, it just hangs.
If I add an argument after npm search in command line, it works fine.